# How to handle TextView OnClick listener on Ripple effect layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-framelayout

I have a cardview which having child ripple layout . Under ripple layout , I have layouts and textviews . **In my class ,I added onclick listener on ripple layout . But  I want to have onclick event on textview which is inside ripple effect .**

**What Happening right now** : *Clicking the layout starts ripple onclick code and Textview onclick code never fires .*

**CardView XML code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    ​<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.LayoutRipple
        android:id="@+id/ripplelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#f5f5f5"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            ​
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header_ll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:weightSum="3.5"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:weightSum="0.4"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp">
                    ​
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/job_number"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="TN1234"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/job_time"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:text="mm,hh:mm"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/job_frame"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2.3"
                    android:weightSum="2.3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/locationimage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/location"/>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:textSize="11sp"
                        android:id="@+id/job_addresstext"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:textColor="#74aadc"
                        android:layout_weight="2.0"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                        android:text="Street Name, Landmark\n Address , Lorem Ipsum"/>
                </LinearLayout>


                </FrameLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:weightSum="0.9"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp">


                    ​ <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/timerimage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/timer"/>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/job_timertext"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:text="HH:MM"/>

                    ​</LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_ll"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp">
                ​
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/instruction_label"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="XYZ wrote:"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/instruction_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum"
                    android:textColor="#727272"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
                ​
            </LinearLayout>
            ​
        <!--</RelativeLayout>-->
        ​            </com.gc.materialdesign.views.LayoutRipple>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    ​
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Ripple effect listener**

```
 holder.ripplelayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SingleTon.getInstance().setWorkDescHolder(mDataset.get(position).descHolder);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager =  ((FragmentActivity) mAct).getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft =  ((FragmentActivity) mAct).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.glide_fragment_horizontal_in, R.anim.glide_fragment_horizontal_out);
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame1, new DetailsFragment(), "persondetails");
                ft.addToBackStack("persondetails");

                // Start the animated transition.
                ft.commit();

            }
        });
```

**Frame Layout inside which textview exist on which wanted click event :**

```
holder.frameLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String map = "http://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=" + mDataset.get(position).address;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(map));
                mAct.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

I tried using frame layout for textview but nothing is working .
Please help me with suggestions and code .